# $B/K$ is a field extension of degree 1 implies $B = K$?

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I was reading the fundamental theorem of Galois theory. Here's an excerpt.

> **Theorem**. Let $E/F$ be a finite Galois extension, then
>   $$ \varphi: K \mapsto Aut(E/K) $$
>   and
>   $$ \psi: H \mapsto E^H$$
>   are bijections between the set of the intermediate fields and subgroups of $Gal(E/F)$.
>
> **Partial proof**. We show $\psi \varphi$ is the identity map.
>
> Let K be an intermediate field, then $E/K$ is a Galois extension, thus
>   $ |Aut(E/K)| = [E:K] $. Let $B = E^{Aut(E/K)}$, then $B \supset K$. $E/B$ is also a Galois extension, and
>   $$ [E:B] = |Aut(E/K)| = [E:K] $$
>   So $B = K$, that is $\psi \varphi $ is the identity map.

I'm not sure with the last argument. We know that $[B:K] = [E:K] / [E:B] = 1$. But does this always imply $B=K$?

Comment: Yes (equal, or isomorphic, depends on the context).

Comment: @Bernard isomorphic, of course. What about equality?

Comment: Wait a sec. Why are they isomorphic? I only know they're isomorphic as vector spaces.

Comment: $\psi\varphi$  is a field homomorphism because $\operatorname{Aut}(E/K)$ denotes the $K$-algebra automorphisms of $E$.

Comment: @Bernard Can you elaborate more? I don't get it.

Comment: I didn't explain correctly. That $\operatorname{Aut}(E/K)$ denotes the $K$-algebra homomorphisms  of $E$ implies $B$ is a subfield of $E$, which contains $K$. $[B:K]=1$ implies $B=K$ (if $B\varsupsetneq K$, its dimension would be at least $2$).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since $B$ contains $K$, it has the structure of a vector space over $K$.  We know $K \subseteq B$, and we want to show that $B \subseteq K$.

The dimension of $B$ over $K$ is $1$, so there exists a basis of $B$ over $K$ consisting of a single element.  In other words, there exists a $v \in B$ with the property that every element of $B$ can be written as $kv$ for some $k \in K$.  In particular, $1 \in B$, so $1 = k_0v$ for some $k_0 \in K$.  Hence $v$ is the inverse of $k_0 \in K$.  Hence $v \in K$.

Now every element of $B$ is a product of two elements of $K$, hence every element of $B$ is in $K$.

Comment: I tacitly used the fact that for fields $K \subseteq B$, $1_K = 1_B$ (and I just refer to that thing as $1$).  But this is easy to see.

Comment: Thanks! Can I have an example where $v \neq 1$ can be a basis?

Comment: If $K$ is a field, then any nonzero element of $K$ is a basis for $K$ as a vector space over itself.